# How can I install Matlab from the Mathworks website?

Tags: software-installation, matlab

When downloading [Matlab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) from the [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/) website, I am prompted to download an .flp file. When I open this JAVA file I shortly see a screen where some data is processed and after that nothing ever happens again.

Does anybody have an idea how to install Matlab this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install Matlab using this installer, you have to install the official Sun Java JRE.

Got to Applications -> Software Center and select Software Sources from the Edit menu

[image]

Select Canonical Partners under Other Software and click on close

Now search for sun-java-6 and install the packages

[image]

Finally, right click on your downloaded Matlab installation file and click on Open With Sun Java 6 Runtime

Answer (score 2):

In order to install Matlab using this installer, you have to install the official Sun Java JRE. This is no longer available in *Maverick's* repositories.

One workaround for this is to select the archives from *Lucid* and install JAVA from there.

Comment: Figured it out myself....

Comment: Lucid is the current version remember... ;)

Comment: Uargh, you are right! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Sun Java from the partner repository, this can be done by enabling the repository through the menu System>Administration>Software Sources, in the "Other Software" tab check the one saying something with partner.

Then install sun-java6-bin package and activate it by running

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

in a terminal.

Afterwards you should be able to run Matlab as you tried it before.

Comment: "Software Sources" is no longer available in Maverick. I could not find JAVA in those repositories anyways when activating them from Synaptic. Seems like they have taken it out.

Comment: You didn't say what version of Ubuntu you were using so i just reasoned that you must be using the latest stable release..

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is java, then check [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/how-to-install-java-jre-and-java-plugin.html) workaround, then, for instruction on how install mathlab (R2009b) see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB/R2009b)